# Database form does display results

Tags: php

I am having trouble displaying my results in the form. Could anyone show me what I am doing wrong? The only thing that is showing up is the echo Database Output. I am trying to create a database to update a webpage. I am suppose to go to the admin page which contains this form and should be able to add, delete and update the webpage any suggestions would help. Thanks in advance.

```
</head>
<body>
<?php
$id=$_POST['id'];
$db="";
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');
if (! $link)
die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");

mysql_select_db($db , $link)
or die("Couldn't open $db: ".mysql_error());

$query=" SELECT * FROM tblContent WHERE PageID ='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();

echo "<b><center>Database Output</center></b><br><br>";

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$pageHeading=mysql_result($result,$i,"PageHeading");
$subHeading=mysql_result($result,$i,"SubHeading");
$contentTxt=mysql_result($result,$i,"Content");
$pageTitle=mysql_result($result,$i,"PageTitle");
$metaDescription=mysql_result($result,$i,"MetaDescription");
$metaKeywords=mysql_result($result,$i,"MetaKeywords");
?>  
<form method="post" action="admin.php">
<input type="hidden" name="ud_id value="<? echo $id; ?>">                          
LinkText: <input type="text" name="ud_LinkText" value="<? echo $contectTxt; ?>"><br>
Page Heading:<input type="text" name="ud_PageHeading"  value="<? echo $id; ?>">
Sub Heading:<input type="text" name="ud_SubHeading" 
value="<? echo $subHeading; ?>"><br>
Page Title: <input type="text" name="ud_PageTitle" value="<? echo $pageTitle; ?>"><br>
MetaDescription: <input type="text" name="ud_MetaDescription" 
value="<? echo $metaDescription; ?>"><br>
MetaKeywords: <input type="text" name="ud_MetaKeywords" 
value="<? echo $metaKeywords; ?>"><br>
<input type="Submit" value="Update">
</form>

<?php
++$i;
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *sigh* http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
$db="";  //add your database name here
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably get an error message due to this mis spelled function:

```
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
```

should be

```
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: I changed and it still comes up the same. I know I'm connected because there is no errors showing up. Thanks anyway for trying!

Comment: Also here is my table I created if that will help.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblContent` (
  `PageID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `PageHeading` varchar(150) default NULL,
  `SubHeading` varchar(150) default NULL,
  `Content` text,
  `PageTitle` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `MetaDescription` mediumtext,
  `MetaKeywords` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`PageID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;